# Data analysis on .json file in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have to analyse a .json file which looks like this:

```
{"columns":["id","timestamp","offset_freq","reprate_freq"],
"index":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ... 
"data":[[526144,1451900097533,20000000.495000001,250000093.9642499983],[...    }
```

it has over 600000 indexes so I dont want to show you the whole file.

I have found out that I can read the file simply by:

```
df = pd.read_json(file_name_or_Python_string, orient='split')
```

But what do I do now if I want to do some math on one of the columns?
For example devide all the offset_freq by 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to divide 'offset_freq' by 2:

```
df['offset_freq']/2
```

I suggest you read 10 minutes to pandas for a quick pandas primer

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to parse the json and save into python data structures or objects for easy manipulation. How exactly you want to implement that depends on your needs and preferences.